# Second order linear ode with variable coefficient and imaginary roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ode:$$t^2y''+ty'+y=0$$

The solution should be of the form $$y=t^r$$

So:

$t^2(t^r)''+t(t^r)'+t^r=0$
$$...$$

$t^r(r^2+1)=0$

$r_1=i$ and $r_2=-i$

$y_1=c_1e^{it}$ and $y_2=c_2e^{-it}$

Using Eulers Formula we get

$y_1=c_1(cost+isint)$ and $y_2=c_2(cost-isint)$

$y(t)=y_1(t)+y_2(t)$

$y(t)=c_1(cost+isint)+c_2(cost-isint)$

$y(t)=cost(c_1+c_2)+isint(c_1-c_2)$

Is this correct? If not where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started off assuming that the solution has the form $t^r$ for some $r$ and correctly obtained $r=\pm i$.

But then you wrote $y_1=c_1e^{it}$ instead of $y_1=c_1t^i$, plugging back into the wrong form.

Instead, go on with $$t^i=\left(e^{\ln(t)}\right)^i=e^{i\ln(t)}=\cos(\ln(t))+i\sin(\ln(t))$$
and you should be able to finish the problem.

Comment: Ohh I see thanks a lot!